# Is it possible to use HTTP (NOT HTTPS) over port 443?

Tags: windows, http, https

I wonder if it is possible to communicate plain HTTP (no SSL) over the TCP port 443?

Trying to change the address of my WCF based server to use the port 443 (but no SSL) fails with this message:

```
Shunra.Common.Wcf.ShunraServiceHost - Open failed with exception
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:443/NC/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:443/NC/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at Shunra.Common.Wcf.ShunraServiceHost.Open() in c:\dev\windows\Common\Shunra.Common\Wcf\ShunraServiceHost.cs:line 65
```

And this is not the matter of HTTP namespace reservation, since the user is an administrator.

So, I am wondering whether there is a special treatment of the port 443 as to only allow HTTPS over it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably ask that at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Also notice that the error message says `Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS.`. So this seems to indicate that another application already uses port 443, and that this is the problem.

Comment: Daniel Gehriger is right, I'm guessing you have IIS running too and it's binding to port 443.

Comment: You are right and indeed killing IIS fixes the problem. But, why don't I have the same problem with other ports that IIS is listening to, like 80?

Comment: Because the IIS host header for the other ports may be different. - converting my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the error message says

> Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS.

So this seems to indicate that another application already uses port 443, and that this is the problem. You can only have several applications listen on the same port if they differ in their host header.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what is a host header?